# Azure Data Factory Connection to Google Big Query Timeout Issues

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I´m trying to **grab Firebase analytics data from Google BigQuery with Azure Data Factory**.

The Connection to BigQuery works but I have quite often timeout issues when running a (simple) query. **3 out of 5 times I run into a timeout**. If no timeout occurs I recive the data as expected.

Can someone of you confirm this issue? Or has an idea what´s the reason for the.

Thanks & best,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Timeout issues could happen in the Azure Data Factory sometimes. It is affected by source dataset, sink dataset, network, query performance and other factors, etc. After all, your connectors are not azure services.

You could try to set `timeout` param follow this [json chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#activity-policy-json-definition). Or you could set `retry` times to deal with timeout issues.

If your sample data is so simple that can't be timeout,maybe you could commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to ask adf team about your concern.

Comment: The issue already appears when I add a Dataset for a Google BigQuery Table. When I try to "preview" the data (no processing, no sink...) I run into a timeout 3 out of 5 times.

If I run the same query directly on BigQuery, I get the result within ~ 2 seconds.

Comment: @Michael So,I suggest you asking azure adf team to figure out how the adf grab the data from google big query and how to improve the query performance. There are no such statements on the official documents.

Comment: Thanks, I will do... Since the last update it works a lot better.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, glad to hear that. If you don't mind, you could adopt the answer for the time being. If you get any actual advice from azure team,you could post here so that i will summarize that in the answer for others' reference.Thanks a lot!